# GNU Make seems to skip prerequisites

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I've got a basic, minimal makefile to compile C++ source; a stripped-down version looks like this:

```
TARGET = main

OBJ = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard *.cpp))
CPPFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall

build: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    @echo "$? --> $@"
    g++ $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $?
    @echo

%.o: %.cpp
    @echo "$< --> $@"
    g++ $(CPPFLAGS) -c $<
    @echo
```

When building from scratch, everything works as expected:

```
clock.cpp --> clock.o
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -c clock.cpp

main.cpp --> main.o
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -c main.cpp

clock.o main.o --> main
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o main clock.o main.o
```

After a change in one of the source files, `make` rebuilds the corresponding object file, but for some reason skips the existing (unchanged) object file when trying to link (`clock.o --> main` instead of `clock.o main.o --> main`):

```
clock.cpp --> clock.o
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -c clock.cpp

clock.o --> main
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o main clock.o
```

When running `make` again, *without changing any file*, the linking works as expected:

```
clock.o main.o --> main
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o main clock.o main.o
```

---

**What's the reason for this behavior, and how could it be prevented?**

*I'm running GNU Make 4.1 on i686 Linux 4.4*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use wrong automatic variable in `g++ $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $?` recipe.
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html:

> **$?**
>
> The names of all the prerequisites that are newer than the target,
>   with spaces between them.

So Make does exactly what you ask it to do: link main target from all updated prerequisites and skip untouched prerequisites.

`g++ $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $^` recipe will fix the problem.